# How to set PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I'm coding a platform with CakePHP3.2.3 . I need to create a database and almost 100 tables on the specific server. I created a sql file for each table, and create the tables on the remote server via read the sql file and execute the sql inside. But I get some error from the CakePHP DebugKit. It says like below

```
Documentation API
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries     
while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). 
Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may 
enable query buffering by setting the 
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

I think fetchAll is not an option for me. But I don't know how to enable query buffering with connection of CakePHP. Please tell me how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer from the source code of CakePHP. We could call the prepare function and then execute the sql to enable buffer.

```
    $path = ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . 'config' . DS . 'sql';
    $dir = new Folder($path);
    $files = $dir->read(true);
    $files = $files[1];
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file = new File($dir->pwd() . DS . $file);
        $sql = str_replace('%s', $tablePrefix, $file->read());

        $buffer = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $buffer->execute();
    }
```